# mysql sqlmode is non strict_mode. But it check not null. and return error

Tags: mysql

I've changed `my.cnf`. and check `sql_mode` use below command

```
select @@global.sql_mode;
```

and It says,

[image: screenShot]

and Also I've tried

```
set global sql_mode='';
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

But... when I query to insert null values into not null column, It returns error...

How Can I turn off strict mode????????

Please help me.....

Comment: "query to insert null into not null, returns error"? Can't you just copy and paste the query and the error? I can't figure out what you want to do but reconfiguring the entire server is not likely to be the best solution. Plus session SQL Mode can override global one anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a not null column to null. the effect of turning ofF sql mode is described https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-invalid-data.html,
*If you are not using strict mode, then whenever you insert an “incorrect” value into a column, such as a NULL into a NOT NULL column or a too-large numeric value into a numeric column, MySQL sets the column to the “best possible value” instead of producing an error* ... *If you try to store NULL into a column that doesn't take NULL values, an error occurs for single-row INSERT statements. For multiple-row INSERT statements or for INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements, MySQL Server stores the implicit default value for the column data type. In general, this is 0 for numeric types, the empty string ('') for string types, and the “zero” value for date and time types*

This is easily demonstrated:-

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SET SESSION SQL_MODE = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT @@sESSION.SQL_MODE;
+--------------------+
| @@sESSION.SQL_MODE |
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | dt         | meeting |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  2 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  3 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  4 | 2017-12-22 |       1 |
|  5 | 2017-12-25 |       1 |
+----+------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (DT,MEETING) VALUES ('2018-01-01',NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'meeting' cannot be null
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (DT,MEETING) VALUES ('2018-01-01',NULL),('2018-01-02',NULL);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.41 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 2

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | dt         | meeting |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  2 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  3 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  4 | 2017-12-22 |       1 |
|  5 | 2017-12-25 |       1 |
| 13 | 2018-01-01 |       0 |
| 14 | 2018-01-02 |       0 |
+----+------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For single inserts the ignore extension

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT ignore INTO T (DT,MEETING) VALUES ('2018-01-10',NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | dt         | meeting |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  2 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  3 | 2017-12-20 |       1 |
|  4 | 2017-12-22 |       1 |
|  5 | 2017-12-25 |       1 |
| 13 | 2018-01-01 |       0 |
| 14 | 2018-01-02 |       0 |
| 15 | 2018-01-10 |       0 |
+----+------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Allows the insert but stores the implicit value as described above.(this also works for multiple row inserts AND doesn't care about strict mode)

Warning turning off sql mode and using insert ignore are very blunt tools - and may be harmful to your db.

Comment: @P.Salmon please check your first sentence... I believe you intended to say *"You cannot set a non-nullable column to null."*

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that MySQL 5.1 and before allowed INSERT NULL values into NOT NULL fields and a lot of apps were written with this precept.

For DBAs, it is not easy to say to all the developers to upgrade MySQL when they have to change so much code.